# Creating decision statements?

Tags: java

The program is supposed to output the growth yield of the investment. The investment amount, the duration and the base rate are to be provided as user input to the program. The growth rate is applied yearly according to the following table:

[image: Table]

All I have so far is the user input code, below,

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InvestGrowth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double investment, duration, baserate, growth;

        investment = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Investment Amount:"));

        duration = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Duration in years: "));

        baserate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter BaseRate:"));

        if (investment <- 50000){

        }
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to create the decision statements for the table... any help?

Comment: Remove the picture of your code and copy paste it in as a code block

Comment: You don't know how to use an `if` statement?

Comment: Since you are learning I think you should first try to make the core logic work in the console before attempting to make the application in Swing/JavaFX (use this not Swing if you are allowed!).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning I think you should first try to make the core logic work in the console before attempting to create a full graphical application.

Try make it work using the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class InvestGrowth {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Investment ($):");
    double investment = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter Duration (Years):");
    double duration = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter Base:" );
    double base  = scanner.nextDouble();

    double growthRate = 0.0;
    double growthYield = 0.0;

    // TODO: Complete actual logic of calculating growthYield
    if (investment <= 50000) {
      if(duration <= 1) { // Investment <= $50000 && Duration <= 1 year

      } else { // Investment <= $50000 && Duration > 1 year

      }
    } else { 
      if (duration <= 1) { // Investment > $50000 && Duration <= 1 year

      } else { // Investment > $50000 && Duration > 1 year

      }
    }

    System.out.println("Your growth yield is: " + growthYield);
  }
}
```

I have left out the core logic as I think that is your homework (so ask your teacher/lecturer/professor/TA etc. If you are stuck) however the part you were stuck on *"decision statements for the table"* is there :)